# How can I use default image if Image url gives 404 error in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-image

I want to load a default image if the image URL gives a 404 error. I tried onError() in image prop but it's not working.

```
<Image
              onError={() => {
                setError(true);
              }}
              source={{
                uri: error
                  ? imageUrl
                  : "https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/udemy-logo-5.png",
              }}
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: "100%",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
```

How can I do this thing?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#defaultsource

Comment: @Horst This only works for ios not in android I guess.

Comment: it is working in release mode.

Comment: But, In the documentation, it is written that "A static image to display while loading the image source." It will only show the image while loading and what if loading completes and the image gives an error Does it show after then also if it fails?

Comment: It would use the static mage from the beginning. Until it get the image sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaultSource in your Image with default image which results in displaying default image when the provided imageUrl fails to load

```
var defaultImage = yourDefaultImageURl
```

And in your Image

```
    <Image
    defaultSource={defaultImage}
    source={{uri: imageUrl}}
       style={{
            height: 50,
            width: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
   resizeMode="cover"
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case how about just placing the default url in error

```
 onError={() => {       
 setImageUrl('https://logodownload.org/wpcontent/uploads/2019/07/udemy-logo-5.png');
          }}
```

And in source

```
       source={{uri:imageUrl}}
```

Comment: This will set the image URL for all if one image fails to load.

Comment: As per the question placed i understand it to be used for a single Image and then this works fine.  Are you loading the same imageUrl elsewhere?

Comment: Yes for the single image it's fine. But I am getting images from the server.

Comment: In that case you can maintain respective ids and flag for each imageUrls and maintain the state accordingly. Doing so can help in refreshing and loading the images with the imageUrls fetched and also the error state.